# Combine 2 SELECTs into one SELECT in my RAILS application

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, performance

I have a table called ORDEREXECUTIONS that stores all orders that have been executed. It's a multi currency application hence the table has two columns CURRENCY1_ID and CURRENCY2_ID.

To get a list of all orders for a specific currency pair (e.g. EUR/USD) I need to lines to get the totals:

```
v = Orderexecution.where("is_master=1 and currency1_id=? and currency2_id=? and created_at>=?",c1,c2,Time.now()-24.hours).sum("quantity").to_d
v+= Orderexecution.where("is_master=1 and currency1_id=? and currency2_id=? and created_at>=?",c2,c1,Time.now()-24.hours).sum("unitprice*quantity").to_d
```

Note that my SUM() formula is different depending on the the sequence of the currencies.
e.g. If I want the total ordered quantities of the currency pair USD it then executes (assuming currency ID for USD is 1 and EUR is 2.

```
v = Orderexecution.where("is_master=1 and currency1_id=? and currency2_id=? and created_at>=?",1,2,Time.now()-24.hours).sum("quantity").to_d
v+= Orderexecution.where("is_master=1 and currency1_id=? and currency2_id=? and created_at>=?",2,1,Time.now()-24.hours).sum("unitprice*quantity").to_d
```

How do I write this in RoR so that it triggers only one single SQL statement to MySQL?

Comment: Is it intentional that the order of c1,c2 in the conditions is different in the 2 queries ?

Comment: Yes, that is intentional. I't the way that the data is stored in the DB.  currency1_id is always the buying currency, currency2_id is the selling currency. I store buys and sells in one single table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this would do:

```
v = Orderexecution.where("is_master=1 
                           and ( (currency1_id, currency2_id) = (?,?)
                              or (currency1_id, currency2_id) = (?,?)
                               )
                           and created_at>=?"
                        ,c1, c2, c2, c1, Time.now()-24.hours
                        )
                  .sum("CASE WHEN currency1_id=? 
                               THEN quantity 
                             ELSE unitprice*quantity 
                        END"
                      ,c1 
                      )
                  .to_d
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks.  Just one glitch, I had to change it to
v = Orderexecution.where("is_master=1 and ( (currency1_id, currency2_id) = (?,?)
 or (currency1_id, currency2_id) = (?,?) ) and created_at>=?",c1, c2, c2, c1, Time.now()-24.hours).sum("CASE WHEN currency1_id=#{c1} THEN quantity ELSE unitprice*quantity END").to_d

I dont quite know why I had to change the SUM part to use =#{c1} instead of the =?   but it kept on giving me an error.

Comment: No idea really, my Ruby skills are very limited. Just tried to translate SQL into it. To tell the truth, 2 queries seem better than 1 in this case. And they may be faster.

Comment: Or one with something like `SELECT (SELECT ...query1) + (SELECT ... query2)`. But that I have no idea how to write in RoR (or if it is even possible).

Answer (score 0):

So you could do

```
SELECT SUM(IF(currency1_id = 1 and currency2_id = 2, quantity,0)) as quantity,
     SUM(IF(currency2_id = 1 and currency1_id = 2, unitprice * quantity,0)) as unitprice _quantity from order_expressions
WHERE created_at > ? and (currency1_id = 1 or currency1_id = 2)
```

If you plug that into `find_by_sql` you should get one object back, with 2 attributes, `quantity` and `unitprice_quantity` (they won't show up in the output of inspect in the console but they should be there if you inspect the attributes hash or call the accessor methods directly)

But depending on your indexes that might actually be slower because it might not be able to use indexes as efficiently. The seemly redundant condition on `currency1_id` means that this would be able to use an index on `[currency1_id, created_at]`. Do benchmark before and after - sometimes 2 fast queries are better than one slow one!